# Change background colour of panel heading when toggled in Bootstrap collapsible panel group

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, collapsable

I am trying to create a collapsible panel group using Bootstrap, and I would like the panel heading to change background colour when the panel group is not collapsed (one colour for collapsed panel group, one for unwrapped). I have tried using the :active selector, but this changes the colour only when clicked, it does not persist longer:

```
 <div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" class="panel-title" href="#collapse1">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.panel-heading a:active {
  background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s625dgty/

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.active` class instead of `:active` pseudo-class which only lasts as long as the user keeps their mouse-button (or pointing device equivalent) down. Target the link's parent `.panel-header` instead:

```
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

The CSS has been modified to override `.panel-heading` with higher specificity by doubling the class:

```
.panel-heading.panel-heading {...
```

Some Bootstrap classes cannot be overridden by cascading priority, just double up on the target class as shown above -- **do not use `!important`**

Also, place `<link>` in the `<head>`. Place `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag. See Demo.

---

#### Demo

```css
.panel-heading.panel-heading.active {
  background: red;
}

.panel-title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-heading.panel-heading.active .panel-title {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="panel-title" href="#collapse1">Title</a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.panel-heading').on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class when user clicked on panel. And then style to new class. let's try this.

## CSS

```
.panel.active {background: red}
```

## JS

```
$('.panel').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active')    
})
```